# Error 'Mismatch of data types....' printed during data migration to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, data-migration

The following error was output during data migration to Magento 2.

If you receive such an error, which file would you like to edit?

Also, please tell me how to write.

```
Mismatch of data types. Source document: paygent_last_id. Fields: payment_notice_id
Mismatch of data types. Source document: sales_flat_order. Fields: shipping_description

Mismatch of data types. Destination document: paygent_last_id. Fields: payment_notice_id
Mismatch of data types. Destination document: sales_order. Fields: shipping_description
```

Answer (score 0):

In your map.xml file you have to add this code into the bottom of the Source tag and the Destination tag

```
<ignore>
    <document>paygent_last_id</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>sales_flat_order</document>
</ignore>
```

I hope that can help you